# Resize and arrange pictures automatically on a canvas

Tags: printing, gimp, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to make a template for printing 9 cards of 63 x 88 mm on a DIN A4 paper.

I want to load the images so that they re-size themselves and I can print them directly.

How can I do that?

Comment: resize on what occasion? There are other possibilities, using imagemagick, drop 4 images in a folder named 1-4 and let a script do the work.

Comment: And will them keep the size when I copy them into gimp?

Comment: I am not sure in what units you are thinking. I think you should decide geometry in pixels (- ratio), while actual size depends on the printing resolution. You can make a script "equalize" images, even combine them and open them with gimp at once. Would the images be of the same ratio? (would you have to crop them or resize canvas ratio?)

Comment: Also: can so explain a bit more on the situation / purpose what it is used for?

Comment: I'm using a DIN A4 paper with 600 ppi so its 4960x7016 pixels. When I drag each file into the paper it is loaded in another layer and then I right click that layer and with the scale layer option put it to 88 mm height and the width changes automatically to the desired 63 mm. Then I move the image to the desired location. And then start with another image. When I have the 9 images loaded I export it to pdf. How can I do this faster?

Comment: are all images of the same orientation? (I assume they are, but to make sure)

Comment: Yes they are all of the same orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below a script to create one file from a number of images. The script uses `imagemagick`.

#### About imagemagick

From `man imagemagick`:
*ImageMagick®, is a software suite to create, edit, and  compose  bitmap images.  It  can read, convert and write images in a variety of formats (about 100) including GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PNG,  PDF,  PhotoCD,  TIFF, and  DPX.  Use ImageMagick  to translate, flip, mirror, rotate, scale, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various  special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bezier curves.*

Since Imagemagick is a command line tool, it is especially fit for use in scripts; to automate jobs like you mention in your question for example.

#### Install Imagemagick

You might have to install imagemagick first:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

#### The script

The script combines and arranges a number of images into one file. Doing so, it uses the maximum space (in `px`), defined by you, but *without changing the image proportions*. Once the job is done, the output is automatically opened in `Gimp` (so `Gimp` should be installed). If for some reason the file does not show up in `Gimp`, it is in your images' folder, named: `out_file.jpg`.

[image]

#### An example

In the example below, your desired output is a sheet of three images (columns) x three images (rows), while the images need to be 1500px (horizontal). You will need an area of 4500px (width), and at the same time make sure the three rows fit in the area. In the head section of the script, you set:

```
colrows = [3, 3]            # set the number of colums/rows
max_area = [4500, 6500]     # set the area (hxv in px) the script can use
```

since the hight is "oversized" for our pictures, the script will fill upt the maximum width (4500/3 = 1500px per image)

The output:

[image]

The script assumes:

- all pictures are of the same proportion & orientation (they may however be of different sizes)
- the number of pictures inside the folder (see above) is equal to (or at least) rows x columns (9 in your example). If there are more images inside the folder, only the needed number is used.

#### Options / settings

The script has a number of options. In the head section of the script, you need to define:

```
img_dir = "/path/to/files"      # path to the images
output_extension = ".jpg"       # desired output
colrows = [3, 3]                # columns  / rows of pictures
max_area = [4500, 6500]         # the (max) size of your sheet
border = 10                     # whitespace around the images
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# set the input below
###############################################################################
img_dir = "/path/to/files"      # path to the images
output_extension = ".jpg"       # desired output
colrows = [3, 3]                # columns  / rows of pictures
max_area = [4500, 6500]         # the (max) size of your sheet
border = 10                     # whitespace around the images 
###############################################################################
cd_topics = "cd "+"'"+img_dir+"'; "
# current picture size
images = sorted([item for item in os.listdir(img_dir)])[:colrows[0]*colrows[1]]
for image in images:
    shutil.copyfile(img_dir+"/"+image, img_dir+"/fixed_"+image.replace(" ", "_"))
images = sorted([item for item in os.listdir(img_dir) if item.startswith("fixed_")]) ##             
# a few functions                    
def get_picsize(image):
    command = cd_topics+'identify -format "%wx%h" '+image
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").strip().split("x")

def resize(img_in, img_out, size, modus=None):
    modus = "^ " if modus == "outsize" else " "    
    newsize = str(size)+"x"+str(size)
    resize_command = cd_topics+"convert "+img_in+" -resize "+newsize+modus+img_out
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", resize_command])

def add_border(img_in, img_out, bd):
    if bd != None and str(bd) != "0":
        addborder_command = cd_topics+"convert "+img_in+" -bordercolor white -border "+bd+"x"+bd+" "+img_out
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", addborder_command])
# make all pictures of equal size
standard_size = get_picsize(images[0])
for pic in images:
    if not get_picsize(pic) == standard_size:
        resize(pic, pic, max(standard_size))   
# calculate resize
picture_orientation = int(standard_size[0])/int(standard_size[1])
area_ratio = float(max_area[0]/max_area[1])
combi_ratio = (colrows[0]*int(standard_size[0]))/(colrows[1]*int(standard_size[1]))
fit_in = area_ratio/combi_ratio
if fit_in > 1:
    newsize = int(max_area[1]/colrows[1])-2*border
    modus = "outsize" if picture_orientation > 1 else None
else:
    newsize = int(max_area[0]/colrows[0])-2*border
    modus = "outsize" if picture_orientation < 1 else None
# resize images
for image in images:
    resize(image, "rs_"+image, newsize, modus)
    add_border("rs_"+image, "rs_"+image, bd=str(border))
# combining into rows
images = sorted([pic for pic in os.listdir(img_dir) if pic.startswith("rs_")])
rows = [images[i:i+colrows[0]] for i in range(len(images)-colrows[0]+1) if i % colrows[0]== 0]
i = 0
while i in range(len(rows)):
    row = rows[i]; images = [im for im in row]
    command = cd_topics+"convert "+" ".join(images)+" +append "+"row_"+str(i+1)+output_extension
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
    i = i+1
# combining rows
images = sorted([pic for pic in os.listdir(img_dir) if pic.startswith("row")])
output_file = "out_file"+output_extension
command = cd_topics+"convert "+(" ").join(images)+" -append "+output_file
subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
# opening image with Gimp, cleaning up
for image in sum([[img for img in os.listdir(img_dir) if img.startswith(string)] \
              for string in ["fixed_", "row_", "rs_"]], []):
    os.remove(img_dir+"/"+image)
command = cd_topics+"gimp "+output_file
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `combine.py`. Set the desired information in the headsection of the script (see `Options / settings`, above).
- Copy the approriate number of pictures into a folder
- Run the script by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/combine.py
  ```

#### A few notes

- The script creates a new image (`outfile`). If you make another combination of the same pictures (-directory) first remove it, or it might appear in the output file.
- The script sorts the images by name, so if you need a particular order, just name them a.jpg, b.jpg and so on.

Comment: Could the images be 1500x2100 pixels with a little of space between them? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Arturo absolutely, will edit and post it tonight.

Comment: could this work with images with spaces in the name? thanks

Comment: @Arturo edited the script, now you can use all the space(s) you need. Also improved another thing; now the script cleans up the temporary pictures it creates to do the job.