# Printing diverse .jpg labels

Tags: printing

I want to print several different labels. I found this code:

```
convert *.jpg my_new.pdf
```

This worked, but it still only prints one label per sheet of paper. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be a command-line or GUI solution, and how many different JPGs/labels need to be printed per sheet?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but would this be a suggestion? http://askubuntu.com/a/549875/72216 It combines different images into a new one of the size and padding that you can define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a PDF directly from JPG using imagemagick, I would use [Libreoffice](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-writer/)  to tile the images onto the sheet size needed, then print directly or export as a PDF - this allows you to easily customize the layout, size, etc (to change the the page size go to Format > Page):

[image]

If you want to use imagemagick and print multiple labels per sheet, it would be possible [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) option to convert to a tiled image (the easiest way to repeat images is to make multiple copies within the folder):

```
convert *.jpg -tile 2x3 out.jpg
```

(to add spacing between each image you can use the geometry option:)

```
convert in*.jpg -tile 2x3 -geometry +2+2 out.jpg
```

Then you can convert that image to a PDF *(if you want a margin of sorts you can try adding a border to the image by adding the options `-border 4x4 -bordercolor "#FFFFFF"`)*. Here I have specified the [page size](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) as A4:

```
convert out.jpg -page A4 -format pdf out.pdf
```

With both these options you may want to check if the DPI (dots per inch - how *not* pixelated it is when printed I supposed) is high enough for what you need to do.